# The Argumant Type ImageProvider Cannot be assigned to the imageprovider

Tags: android, svg, flutter

ı want to , my splash screen show svg file to `CircleAvatar` or `Clip Oval`, But I have a The argument type 'SvgPicture' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

I tried `SvgPicture.asset` function and AssetImage function but ı Couldnt

```
Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 80.0,
                        child:new SvgPicture.asset('assets/yenilogo.svg',fit: BoxFit.contain,colorBlendMode: BlendMode.screen,width: 100,height: 100,)
                      
            
                      ),  //Circle Avatar
```

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcm14.png)
https://ibb.co/b61X6x4

Comment: I don't see the error in your screenshot. You can assign a SVG to a `CircleAvatar`.

Comment: i solved my mistake , ı used svg cleaner and ı deleted style property Thank You!

Comment: The Q/A here would be more useful if you explained what svg cleaner is and how it solved your problem.

Comment: oh ı am soryy , ı used to svg cleaner on this site https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/  , ı drop my svg file and ı reseted my svg file

Answer (score 0):

`SvgPicture` and `Image` are not compatible types.

You either have to rasterize the SVG first, or write your own widget that just gets the canvas (e.g. a CustomPaint or LeafRenderObjectWidget) and paint the SVG on to the canvas.

Comment: i solved my mistake , ı used svg cleaner and ı deleted style property Thank You!